# How to speed up Endless Legend battle animations after a game start?

Tags: endless-legend

`Endless Legend` lets you set a **speed for battle animations** but only **at a world creation step at a start of a game**. How to change it after one has already started a game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me answer this question by quoting [this answer](https://steamcommunity.com/app/289130/discussions/0/522728180904794087/?l=english#c405691491105725177) from the game's `Steam Community` board.

> If you forgot to set the combat speed while creating a new game, you
> can change it in your save file. Locate the zip for the save file
> (usually in your User directory), open the zip, edit
> GameSaveDescriptor.xml by finding the line `<LobbyData Key="EncounterSpeedScaleFactor">1</LobbyData>` and set the number to `3`
> instead of the the default of 1. Make sure the zip is updated with
> your edited file.